# jQuery-Ajax: Append data in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with Ajax using jQuery and I want to append data on the URL. Here's the sample code:

```
var my_site= mysamplesite.com/viewData/";
function showData(myData)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: my_site+"getData"
        data:{
            myData: myData
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data_details){
            $('#data-target').html(data_details.data1+ "\n" +data_details.data2+ "\n" +data_details.data3);
        }
    })
}
```

These function works smoothly but, as I've observed the URL doesn't change (the data doesn't append to the URL) whenever these function is called. So, I want these data to be appended to the URL whenever this function is called.
For example, if the value of data is `1222345`, then I want my URL to be like this:

```
mySampleSite.com/viewData/getData?myData=1222345
```

in which the data is appended to the URL.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @daveͤͮͣͩ Yeah, and it works smoothly. but all i need is to append this data to the URL without reloading the page

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is probably just to append the URL parameter manually instead of using the data parameter of the ajax call.

```
var my_site= "mysamplesite.com/viewData/";
function showData(myData)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: my_site + "getData?myData=" + myData;
        success: function(data_details){
            $('#data-target').html(data_details.data1+ "\n" +data_details.data2+ "\n" +data_details.data3);
        }
    })
}
```

If you need to do it through the data parameter I think your JSON object must be formatted like this: `data:{ "myData": myData }` (note the added quotes).